# Want to know how to control skbuffer

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to adjust the number of packets that merge when creating a socket buffer for GRO in linux kernel. Changing the MAX_SKB_FRAG value still does not change the number of packets that merge. If you know anything, please give me some advice.

```
#if (65536/PAGE_SIZE + 1) < 16
#define MAX_SKB_FRAGS 16UL
#else
#define MAX_SKB_FRAGS (65536/PAGE_SIZE + 1)
#endif
```

I tried changing the defined MAX_SKB_FRAG value, but there was no change. Changing the 65536 value failed to touch it due to an array length error, and other GRO SKB-related values were not affected.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You said (twice) that you changed MAX_SKB_FRAG but the macro is MAX_SKB_FRAGS